# Como puedo traducir a español el mensaje de validacion de un form.error en django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

```
        {% if form.errors %}
                <ul class = "user-msg error">
                    {% for field in form %}
                        {% for error in field.errors %}
                            <li>
                                {% if field != '__all__' %}
                                    <strong>{{ field.label }}:</strong>
                                {% endif %}
                                {{ error }}
                            </li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}



Name: This field is required.
Logo: This field is required.
Country: This field is required.
Type: This field is required.
```

Los mensaje que se muestran son las validaciones,estos mensajes quisiera que se muestren en español. agradecería cualquier codigo fuente o guia para poder solucionar este requerimiento.

Comment: verificaste que tengas en tu settings colocado por defecto el idioma español: LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-ec'

Comment: @DiegoAvila listo, esto no tiene alguna afectación en mi resto de código cuando realizo una actualización de mi proyecto?

Comment: lo unico que afecta es para los mensajes de Django que ahora te mostrara en español

Comment: listo gracias !

Answer (score 0):

En tu `settings.py` pon los siguientes comandos.

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es'
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Lima'
USE_I18N = True
```